# Ajax character encoding, weird going into SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, post, character-encoding

I have 2 asp classic pages, both of which do the same thing.  Take strings and put them in a DB.

Test1.asp:

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%OPTION EXPLICIT%>


<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="../G_FILES/globals.asp"-->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="../g_files/validation.asp"-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=gStyle%>">
<script language="javascript" src="../js_files/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js_files/jquery/jquery.limit-1.2.source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js_files/webdb_helper.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        //CHARACTER COUNT/LIMITATION TEXTAREA
        $('#body').limit('3000', '#charLeft');
    });




    //Save Message
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#saveBtn").click(function() {

            var subject = $('#subject').val();
            var body = $('#body').val();


            var all_good = true;
            //NO ERRORS? INSERT INTO DB


            if (all_good) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "edit_template_test.asp",
                    data: {
                        subject: subject,
                        body: body
                    },
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                        var error = jqXHR.responseText;
                        alert(error);
                    }
                }).done(function(response) {
                    //reload message list
                    alert(response);
                });
            }

        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body style ="width:700px">
<center class="BodyTextBoldDoubleTitle">Service Provider Communications</center><br />

<table class="BodyTextBoldSingle">

    <tr>
        <td>Email Subject:</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" size="91"  maxlength='120' id="subject" value =""/></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Body:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><textarea id='body' rows="13" cols="80"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">You have <font id="charLeft">0</font>/3000 characters left.</td>

    </tr>

    <table class="BodyTextBoldSingle">
        <tr>

            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td><div id="saveBtn" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 40px 40px; background-color: #C0C0C0; height: 25px; width:155px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 25px; cursor: pointer" ><font class="BodyTextBoldSingle">Save</font></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

this calls edit_template_test.asp via ajax:

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%OPTION EXPLICIT%>
<!-- #include file="../g_files/globals.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="../g_files/validation.asp"-->

<%

    dim subject,body

    subject = Request.Form("subject")
    body = Request.Form("body")


        dim db, sql
        set db = Server.CreateObject("Commands.DB")
        sql = "update folder_log set subject = ' " & subject & "', note = '" & body & "' where msg_id       = '00D8EE44-197D-4F95-938E-887005FCE0D6'"
        db.RunCMD g_Conn, sql
        Response.Write subject&"^"&body


    %>
```

Test2.asp:

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%OPTION EXPLICIT%>

<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="../G_FILES/globals.asp"-->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="../g_files/validation.asp"-->
<%

dim body1, subject1
Dim test_send
    test_send= trim(request.Form("test_send"))
if test_send = "yes" then
    Response.Write "hello"
    body1 = request.Form("body2")
    subject1 = request.Form("subject2")

    dim db, sql
    set db = Server.CreateObject("Commands.DB")
    sql = "update folder_log set subject = ' " & subject1 & "', note = '" & body1 & "' where msg_id = '7E59E4EE-6682-4C74-BD65-9F0244742BC5'"
    db.RunCMD g_Conn, sql


end if

 %>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=gStyle%>">
<script language="javascript" src="../js_files/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js_files/jquery/jquery.limit-1.2.source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js_files/webdb_helper.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">


</script>
</head>

<body style ="width:700px">
<form name="test2" id="test2" method="post" action="test2.asp" >
<center class="BodyTextBoldDoubleTitle">Service Provider Communications</center><br />

<table class="BodyTextBoldSingle">

    <tr>
        <td>Email Subject:</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" size="91" name="subject2" maxlength='120' id="subject2" value =""/></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Body:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><textarea name="body2" id="body2" rows="13" cols="80"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">You have <font id="charLeft">0</font>/3000 characters left.</td>

    </tr>

       <tr>

            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="test_send" value="yes" ID="test_send">
            <td><input type="submit" name = "Save"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Both Test1 and Test2 produce the same desired outcomes (entry into DB) except for one thing.

When a string is copied and pasted from Word that contains one of Words different characters (TEST – “TEST” for example), Test2.asp (post back) works perfectly, but Test1.asp will put funky characters into the DB (TEST – “TEST” ->  TEST â€“ â€œTESTâ€).

Has anyone any idea why the post back would work fine but the ajax route has encoding problems?

I have tried all sorts of solutions to get it to work. ie:

```
contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
                    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                        jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
                    },
```

And other types of methods of encoding/decoding.  I really want to get the ajax method working.

Anyone got an explanation?

If it is relevant the char encoding within the sql server is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: Using all capitals in the title is considered SHOUTING. Try to avoid that.

Comment: Oh, ok my bad. Hmm is there a way to edit titles?

Comment: Someone did it for me. Nice, ty!

Comment: Post something on SO for 30 seconds and SOMEONE will mess with it. ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but suppose someone entered a subject of "my subject', msg_id = '0".  That would cause a big integrity problem and much worse could be done.  You should always use parameterized queries.

Comment: the query is just a quick example.  The issue is encoding problems and how using post back method works and ajax doesn't.

Comment: I guess the html fields and textareas contents are encoded using the HTML page encoding, so if the page defaults to UTF-8 you will get UTF-8 text sent to a Latin 1 database. One way to try if this is the case is to set manually (in the browser) the page encoding to Latin 1 before clicking the button to send the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to character encoding. Ensure that you've saved all your .ASP files with UTF-8 encoding (open them in e.g. Notepad, select File > Save As and select UTF-8 encoding in the Save As dialog).

Also you should change your code in "edit_template_test.asp" to get rid of any nasty SQL-injects (imagine if you was sent **'; DROP TABLE ... --** in the subject parameter). Do something like this:

```
dim subject,body

subject = Request.Form("subject")
body = Request.Form("body")

dim db, sql
set db = Server.CreateObject("Commands.DB")
sql = "update folder_log set subject = ' " & Replace(subject,"'","''") & "', note = '" & Replace(body,"'","''") & "' where msg_id       = '00D8EE44-197D-4F95-938E-887005FCE0D6'"
db.RunCMD g_Conn, sql
Response.Write Server.HtmlEncode(subject&"^"&body)
```

Anyway, saving the files in UTF-8 encoding should switch all browsers to render and post data in UTF-8. If not, you might need to do something like this for ASP classic: [Classic ASP's Request.Form is dropping an 8-bit character -- is there a simple way to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747478/classic-asps-request-form-is-dropping-an-8-bit-character-is-there-a-simple-w)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DOCTYPE` declaration from Test1.asp

Also 
        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
is just a [collation property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039321/1601926) for SQL server (default:ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

`javascript` and thus `ajax` standard encoding for strings is **always** `utf8`!
so before passing your strings to your `ajax` functions, be sure to convert them to `utf8`.
and when receiving them from `ajax`, be aware that you received `utf8` encoded strings and then convert them into any encoding you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

on the head of your html file

Why UTF-8:

> UTF-8 supports more characters than ASCII, allowing international
>   languages to be represented.